# Typeahead.js and JSON data from PHP file

Tags: php, json, typeahead.js

I am trying to return some products to a input field with the class set to typeahead. I currently have a php page that I made to query the database and return the results via JSON. When I echo the response I get the following:

```
[
{
    "id": "97",
    "Product": "Amazon  Fire TV",
    "Description": "Amazon - Fire TV Streaming Device - Black"
},
{
    "id": "98",
    "Product": "Amazon Aurum Ultra Series - High Speed HDMI Cable (100 Ft) With Ethernet - Supports 3D",
    "Description": "High Speed HDMI Cable With Ethernet - Supports 3D & Audio Return Channel"
},
{
    "id": "99",
    "Product": "Amazon Eco Dot",
    "Description": "Amazon Eco Dot"
},
{
    "id": "100",
    "Product": "Amazon Fire TV",
    "Description": "Amazon Fire TV"
},
{
    "id": "101",
    "Product": "Amazon Linear 5445 ChannelPlus Four-Channel Video Modulator",
    "Description": "Four-Channel Video Modulator"
},
{
    "id": "102",
    "Product": "Amazon Pyle PCM20A 40 Watts Power Amplifier with 25 and 70 Volt Output",
    "Description": "70 Volt Power Amplifier with 400 Watts"
}
]
```

The issue that I am having is that my typeahead input box is not displaying this data. Here is the code I have for that section in my head section of HTML page.

```
<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
       var Product = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {
            url: '/includes/estimate-search.php?query=%QUERY',
            wildcard: '%QUERY'
        }
      });

  $('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
        name: 'Product',
        source: Product
    });
  });
</script>
```

My PHP code to parse the results are the following:

```
<?php
require_once('../database/connection.php');

$query = $_GET['query']; // add % for LIKE query later

// do query
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `id`, `Product`, `Description` FROM `products` WHERE `Product` LIKE '%".$query."%'");
$stmt->bindParam(':query', $query, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

// populate results
$results = array();
foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
    $results[] = array('id' => $row['id'],  'Product' => $row['Product'], 'Description' => $row['Description']);
}

// and return to typeahead
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($results, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
return json_encode($results);
?>
```

What am I missing that is causing the results to not be displayed by the typeahead api? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: For a starter, error handling and log entries.

Comment: You are echoing and returning json encoded results. Is it a bug or a feature? But it seems to be not the reason for your failure...

Comment: I just have it echo so I could make sure that I was getting the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Had to change to the following to make it work:

PHP File:

```
<?php
require_once('../database/connection.php');
$query = $_GET['query'];
$result = array();
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `Product` FROM `products` WHERE `Product` LIKE :query");
$stmt->bindValue(':query', '%' . $query . '%' );
$stmt->execute();

foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
    $result[] = array('Product' => $row["Product"]);
}
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Head Script file:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
      var Product = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace('Product'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {
            url: '/includes/estimate-search.php?query=%QUERY',
            wildcard: '%QUERY'
        }
      });

  $('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
        name: 'product-search',
        display: 'Product',
        source: Product.ttAdapter()
    });
  });
</script>
```